# Returning a promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, rsvp.js

I have a promise here:

```
myPromise: ->
  return new Em.RSVP.Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    # ...
    resolve 5
```

How do I write a function to return the promise from `myPromise()`?

This is what I've tried:

```
myPromise2: ->
  return myPromise()

myPromise2().then ->
   console.log 'this is never called!'
```

Comment: @TJonS I edited the question to make it more clear what I've tried

Comment: +1 for the edit. And for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
myPromise2: ->
  new Em.RSVP.Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    myPromise()
    resolve()
```